# java process hangs, jvisualvm shows the process is using the all of the heap space

Tags: java, heap-memory

My java process hangs. It reads input data and parses it into Integer[] and write them into disks.

jvisualvm shows the process is fully using the heap space.
(java.lang.Integer and java.lang.Integer[] use 77% and 22% of the heap space respecitvely)

AFAIK the java process dies showing OutOfMemory error messages when the memory capacity is not enough.

Why my process hangs there?
How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: If you want to get an answer to your question try to post your code. Without the code I can only suggest you to try to increase you heap size: - Xmx option. If problem is still there you should take a look at how you free your resources: do you really need all those Integer and Integer[] while the program is running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have a full heap dump, what you will want to do is calculate the fully retained sizes of your objects.  This will tell you the full size of all instances of your class, including the other objects to which it's holding a reference.  Take the largest ones and start from there.

[image: Retained sizes in Visual VM]